# What is the equivalent to (ftp commands) !PWD and LCD , in SSH

Tags: ssh, ftp

To transfer files with ftp I've been setting local directory with `LCD /home/user/` and then setting the remote dir with `cd /domain/folder`. To check the current folder I use `PWD` (for remote) or `!PWD` (for local).

Is there a similar way to do this with an SSH connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while `ssh` doesn't directly support what you are trying to do, it does have some tools that may be useful.

**To get a directory of $HOME.**

```
ssh <user>@<host> ls
```

**To get a directory of /tmp.**

```
ssh <user>@<host> "(cd /tmp; ls)"
```

**To upload a file to your home directory**

```
scp <filename> <user>@<host>:.
```

**To upload a file to: /tmp/z.sh**

```
scp <filename> <user>@<host>:/tmp/z.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking about SSH or SFTP? SSH, as mentioned, is not a file transfer protocol but a family of different protocols for different tasks. SFTP which is a remote filesystem access protocol running usually over SSH, is indeed used for file transfer.

SFTP always uses absolute paths, and the behavior of the server when you pass it a relative path or no path depends on server software and current settings and permissions of remote system. So you need to change your code to conform to SFTP rules rather than try to use SFTP in FTP way.

Answer (score 1):

No. SSH is not a file transfer protocol; it doesn't care what its local directory is (and it doesn't do anything with it).